# Unable to receive only JSON from JQuery ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Here is my js code.

```
....
var arrayData = {"projectId": projectId, "stateId":stateId};
$.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              url: "/bidboldly/projects/editproject/",                
              data: arrayData,
              success : function(response) {                            
                    alert(response);            
              },
              error: function(){
                    alert("error");
              }
            })
```

Server side.

```
$city = $this->City->find('list',array('conditions' =>array('City.status'=>1, 'City.state_id'=>$this->params['url']['stateId']),'fields'=>array('City.id','City.city'),'order'=>array('City.city ASC')));
            echo json_encode($city);
```

After that in client side I've recieved city list + html. Something like this.

```
..."Young America" [20292]=> string(10) "Zanesville" } <html><head>......
```

Why is HTML transfered ?

Comment: What else are you doing in the script? Are you using a framework which puts any output in a template? `"Young America" [20292]=> string(10) "Zanesville" }` does not really look like JSON either (more like `var_dump`).

Comment: @Ghommey are you kidding ? :)

Comment: @FelixKling I use cakePHP framework.

Comment: Then this might be it. I don't know cakePHP, though I assume they provide documentation about how to turn this off.

Comment: cakePHP is adding the html - `exit` might help. I am not kidding.

Comment: I've heard enough cakephp problems, weird problems that arise seemingly without any consistent reason. Now i shut up, never personally tried it...

Comment: @Sampo that is the price you have to pay for all the magic that comes with it

Comment: Is there a reason youre setting the `content-type` header instead of using the `dataType: 'json'` element in your ajax settings?

Comment: yes when I set  dataType: 'json' I've got alert("error").

Comment: That probably means somethings wrong with the returning data - eg. you didnt turn off the layout and you have html mixed in :-)

Comment: @prodigitalson: `contentType` sets the content type of the data which is *sent to the server*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article http://book.cakephp.org/1.1/view/316/Helpers says you should use the ajax render layout:

```
$this->layout = "ajax";
```

Another page full of helpful articles on ajax and cake php is this one:
http://ahsanity.wordpress.com/2007/02/23/get-started-with-ajax-in-cakephp/

Comment: This is reason why I like to write my own fw's, debugging is a lot easier when you know what should be going on. +1 for digging that up :p

Comment: @Sampo: Well if you have worked with and read the documentation for any framework then you general know whats going. Having written and knowing it because you created is not as good as having clear documentation IMO - because you are then the only one that knows and more than likely you will not always be around to help maintain the project. Also that shoudnt be taken as me advocating for Cake... im am not a fan.. AT ALL :-)